# Messy Excel Dates to propper Python Pandas Date

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a column in a Pandas Dataframe, called 'Excel_Date'. This column data looks like this:

```
Excel_Date
Before Q1 2018
Before Q1 2014
Before Q4 2018
42457
42457
42520
nan
nan
```

The column's dtype('O').

I have no idea how I can get this in a proper way.

**Desired Output**

```
Excel_Date
Before Q1 2018 #Or even better: the first month and day of Q1 (1/1/2018)
Before Q1 2014 #Or even better: the first month and day of Q1 (1/1/2014)
Before Q4 2018 #Or even better: the first month and day of Q4 (10/1/2018)
3/28/2016
3/28/2016
5/30/2017
nan
nan
```

The '#Or even better:... '  in the example would amazing! But I can understand that that could be a bit difficult.

**What have I tried?**

I tried to divide the problem, into smaller sub problems:

```
 1. Create a column, with only the numeric values
 > df['Excel_Date2'] = df['Excel_Date'].str.extract("(\d*\.?\d+)", expand=True

 2. After that, I tried to deal with the numbers. But I failed.    
 >import datetime as dt
 >import pandas as pd
 >pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['Excel_Date2'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
```

Many, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get only numeric values and then use your solution:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['Excel_Date'], errors='coerce')

df['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(s,unit='d').add(pd.datetime(1899,12,30)).fillna(df['Excel_Date'])
print (df)
       Excel_Date                  new
0  Before Q1 2018       Before Q1 2018
1  Before Q1 2014       Before Q1 2014
2  Before Q4 2018       Before Q4 2018
3           42457  2016-03-28 00:00:00
4           42457  2016-03-28 00:00:00
5           42520  2016-05-30 00:00:00
6             NaN                  NaN
7             NaN                  NaN
```

And better is export quartals, convert to datetimes and last repalce missing values by datetimes from quartals:

```
df1 = df['Excel_Date'].str.extract("(Q[1-4])\s+([1-2]\d{3})", expand=True)
s1 = pd.to_datetime(df1[1] + df1[0])
s2 = pd.to_numeric(df['Excel_Date'], errors='coerce')

df['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(s2, unit='d').add(pd.datetime(1899, 12, 30)).fillna(s1)
print (df)
       Excel_Date        new
0  Before Q1 2018 2018-01-01
1  Before Q1 2014 2014-01-01
2  Before Q4 2018 2018-10-01
3           42457 2016-03-28
4           42457 2016-03-28
5           42520 2016-05-30
6             NaN        NaT
7             NaN        NaT
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Both solutions are working perfectly. Thanks @jezrael!